# Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: docker

Have you ever get an error during the XM cloud installation via docker like this one?

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Unable to connect to the remote server
At C: \Users \ionut.plesescu Desktop Repositories \client-dotcom up-ps1:59
**+ ...   $status = Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost:8079/api/http/routers ...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException      
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand**
```

I enabled `wsl 2` from Docker, disabled `defaultProxy` from `.NET/machine.config` and did everything suggested on internet but got no success in resolving this issue.

Machine being used is not personal machine but provided by my organization, if it matters.
I have run `./down.ps1`, `cd ./docker/clean.ps1`, `./up.ps1` and still same error.

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly add the error message in the text for SEO purposes.

Comment: Done @SumitBhatia. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked for errors on the CM container? Is the CM container up and running?

Comment: No, no containers open when i run ./up.ps1

Comment: Go to Docker Dashboard, and try checking your containers and its logs. I doubt your few containers are unhealthy and it is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that no VPN is enabled on your PC, then do the following steps:

1. Uncheck **Use Docker Compose V2** in docker
2. run `./down.ps1` , `cd ./docker/clean.ps1`
3. delete `.pem` file in `./docker/traefik/certs`
4. run `./up.ps1`

if that still does not work, try to re-run `./init.ps1` with the required params.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons but you can follow some basic steps as generally we do if we get similar kind of error -

1. Run .`/down.ps1`
2. Run `./up.ps1`

If this doesn't work then run `./init.ps1`

If the above doesn't work then try -

- Stop-Service docker
- Stop-service hns
- Start-service hns
- Start-Service docker
- docker network prune

And then follow the above steps -

1. Run `./down.ps1`
2. Run `./up.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the `down.ps1` file, then re-run `init.ps1`, and finally the `up.ps1`. Sometimes it happens that the variables have to be recreated, that’s why we have to do an Init again. It’s a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many possibility for this error. When I encountered it, it was because of a invalid license that was mounted. To further help, navigate to your cm docker container's powershell and post the error messages you receive when you run the below command.

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost -UseBasicParsing
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helped but cleaning up everything with the command:

```
docker system prune -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the same issue by following below steps:

1. run `./down.ps1`
2. run `docker system prune -a`
3. **Stopped the IIS**, whenever we are running docker we need to make sure IIS is stopped. I think this was the main reason for me to face the above issue in the first place.
4. run `./init.ps1`
5. run `./up.ps1`